# create multiple blocks in asciidoctorj plugin

Tags: groovy, asciidoctor

a blockProcessor in a asciidoctorj groovy plugin is capable of returning one block. So, it is easy to transform a block into another one.

What I couldn't find is some kind of documentation on how to create several blocks in one blockProcessor and what kind of blocks are available.

Any idea on how to return two instead of one blocks? I've already tried to play around with the `parent` parameter but couldn't get a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 years later ...
I was able to build a list of child Blocks in a BlockProcessor in this way:

```
Map<String,Object> argAttributes = new HashMap<String,Object>();
argAttributes.put("content_model",":raw");
Block block = createBlock(parent,"open", "", argAttributes, new HashMap<Object,Object>());
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){ // do your business
    List<String> all = ... 
    Block child = createBlock(block,"literal",all, new HashMap<String,Object>(), new HashMap<Object,Object>() );
    block.getBlocks().add(child);
}
return block;
```

Comment: I discovered it yesteday and I'm working on it right now but I hope to finish the new asciidoctor extension soon 

Meanwhile you can check others I have develop at https://gitlab.com/puravida-software/asciidoctor-extensions/

Comment: great! Thanx for sharing! and +1 for using gitlab :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find an answer by analyzing the sources, but I had no success.
My current feeling is that through the combination of java and ruby, the asciidoctorj extension point is currently "broken" so that it is not possible to add several blocks to a `parent` block.